# Maven is not searching online for dependencies (intelij)

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I started a new maven project in intellij and it doesn't seem to have any response when copy/pasting the dependencies (meaning no bar loading in the bottom-right corner). I can't figure out the problem since there is no problem in the other projects, only when I start a new one(a solution is to copy/paste the dependency in an existing project and then to the new one). Another solution is to restart intellij. Does anyone had a similar problem or knows what I need to configure in order to automatically start searching and downloading the dependencies?

Comment: What is your IntelliJ Version?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam I had to reinstall it, so the latest 2020.2.3